# How to add credit by default in WHMCS

Tags: php, sql, billing, whmcs

How can I add default credit in WHMCS?

I mean when a user signup with WHMCS, they will receive some predefined credit balance in their account (credits can be used to purchase products)

I did search but didn't get any result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use WHMCS hook system together with the API.
I haven't tested this code, but it should work more or less out of the box.

Create a file in includes/hooks/

```
add_hook('ClientAreaRegister', 1, function($vars) {
    $command = "addcredit";
    $adminuser = "admin";
    $values["clientid"] = $vars['userid];
    $values["description"] = "Adding credits via ClientAreaRegister hook";
    $values["amount"] = "40.00";

    $results = localAPI($command,$values,$adminuser);
});
```

Make sure you have a user "admin" or create a new user and change above code to match.

References:
https://developers.whmcs.com/hooks-reference/client-area-interface/#clientarearegister
http://docs.whmcs.com/API:Add_Credit

Comment: Thanks for the code. I am not too advanced with these codes. What should I do next? Creating this file in hooks folder will add the specified amount to every new registered user?

Comment: If you are not that experienced with coding you might need someone to assist you, but you can try to add that as a file in hooks folder. Remember to start with <?php in the file.

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for the info. added the php tag, but my entire website goes on HTTP error when I use this code.

Comment: I get HTTP ERROR 500